# Authentication Services module

Tags: 7, services

I use [***services***](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) with ***drupal 7***, here the ***services resources*** function :

```
function custom_api_services_resources()
{
    return [
        'res' => [
            'create' => [
                'callback' => 'custom_api_create_user',
                'access arguments' => array('administer access control'),
                'access arguments append' => FALSE,
                    'args' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'data',
                        'type' => 'struct',
                        'description' => 'data',
                        'optional' => FALSE,
                        'source' => 'data'
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

Here the ***node access*** function (empty) :

```
function custom_api_node_access($op, $data) { 
}
```

For Authentication I use ***HTTP basic authentication*** and/or ***Session authentication***

I don't know what I have to do to limit access only for admin. I've tried a lot but never work with authentication.

I feel like it's very easy to use it, but I don't understand it.

I've already posted a message about this issue but differently. Can someone delete the first one, please ?  [How do I use the access arguments?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208682/how-do-i-use-the-access-arguments/208711#208711)

---

## Edit

### custom_api.module file :

```
             'create' => [
                'callback' => 'custom_api_create_users',
                'access callback' => 'custom_api_access_callback',
                'access arguments' => array('administer create field_projects'),
                'access arguments append' => TRUE,
                'access callback file' => array(
                  'type' => 'inc',
                  'module' => 'support',
                  'name' => 'custom_api.resource',
                ),
                    'args' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'data',
                        'type' => 'struct',
                        'description' => 'data',
                        'optional' => FALSE,
                        'source' => 'data'
                    ]
                ]
```

### custom_api.resource.inc :

```
function custom_api_access_callback($permission) {
  return user_access($permission);
}
```

### Permission from Database, role_permission table :

**Permission :** access comments
**Module :** comment

**Permission :** access content
**Module :** node

**Permission :** access news feeds
**Module :** aggregator

**Permission :** access site map
**Module :** site_map

**Permission :** create field_credits
**Module :** field_permissions

**Permission :** create field_credit_level_1
**Module :** field_permissions

**Permission :** create field_credit_level_2
**Module :** field_permissions

**Permission :** create field_credit_level_3
**Module :** field_permissions

**Permission :** create field_level
**Module :** field_permissions

**Permission :** create field_number_of_credit_remove
**Module :** field_permissions

**Permission :** create field_projects
**Module :** field_permissions

**Permission :** create field_remove_credit
**Module :** field_permissions

**Permission :** search content
**Module :** search

**Permission :** subscribe to newsletters
**Module :** simplenews

**Permission :** use advanced search
**Module :** search

**Permission :** use custom search
**Module :** custom_search

**Permission :** use custom search blocks
**Module :** custom_search_blocks

**Permission :** use text format guestbook_txt
**Module :** filter

**Permission :** access comments
**Module :** comment

**Permission :** access content
**Module :** node

**Permission :** access news feeds
**Module :** aggregator

**Permission :** access site map
**Module :** site_map

**Permission :** administer custom search
**Module :** custom_search

**Permission :** administer custom search blocks
**Module :** custom_search_blocks

**Permission :** administer search
**Module :** search

---

I have link to add data (client and node : *project and client*) in drupal website. Only administrators can add data.

Comment: Why are you using `hook_node_access` for creating a user?

Comment: Actually, I create three entities "user", "client" and "project"... I thought to use this hook to limit access.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal Services is a bit strange in that it doesn't seem to fall back to calling the `user_access()` function. Instead, I always provide a custom `access callback` function, and in it usually just make a call to `user_access()`. Try this:

```
'doli' => [
        'create' => [
            'callback' => 'custom_api_create_user',
            'access callback' => 'example_access_callback',
            'access arguments' => array('administer access control'),
            'access arguments append' => TRUE,
            'access callback file' => array(
              'type' => 'inc',
              'module' => 'example',
              'name' => 'example.resource',
            ),
                'args' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'data',
                    'type' => 'struct',
                    'description' => 'data',
                    'optional' => FALSE,
                    'source' => 'data'
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
```

Then make a file called `example.resource.inc` in your module's folder, and place this code into it:

```
function example_access_callback($permission) {
  return user_access($permission);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tyler for your answer but it doesn't work, I got this message with postman tool : "Access denied for user Name". Let me know if you require any further information.

Comment: Please verify the machine name of the permission you are checking against. For example, I don't recognize the `administer access control` permission, which module provides that?

Comment: Yes, it's not `administer access control` but `administrator`. If I use "Session authentication" I got this message :  "Access denied for user anonymous", if I use "HTTP basic authentication" I got : "Access denied for user Swarovski"...

Comment: no idea ? I got this error : `401 Unauthorized`. I use `administrator access content` permission ... Don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: The permission name is probably `administer nodes` and/or `access content`.

Comment: with, without, and, or ... nothing happens... in Database the role name for admin is `administrator`. I'll post here all my code in the evening. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You'll definitely need permission machine names, not a role machine name.

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: I've edited my first post.